# Change XeTeX Glyph Size

Tags: xetex, symbols, unicode

How would you increase the size of the following glyph?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\font\myfont = "Wingdings"

\begin{document}%
\raggedright

\myfont\XeTeXglyph190

\end{document}
```

Comment: For example,
`\font\myfont = "Wingdings" at 20pt`.

Comment: Perfect. That's fantastic. Thanks very much.

Comment: If you loaded the font using latex font declarations rather than the `\font` primitive then latex size commands such as `\large` or `\fontsize{..}{..}` would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As David Carlisle says in the comments, don't use TeX font loading commands in LaTeX. Load the font properly using LaTeX commands and everything works as you expect.  It's helpful to define a `\text...{...}` command for fonts declared with `\newfontfamily`.  I've shown how to do that too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\myfont{Wingdings}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textwing}{\myfont}

\begin{document}%
\raggedright
{\footnotesize\textwing{\XeTeXglyph190}}
{\textwing{\XeTeXglyph190}}
{\large\textwing{\XeTeXglyph190}}
{\Large\textwing{\XeTeXglyph190}}
{\huge\textwing{\XeTeXglyph190}}
{\Huge\textwing{\XeTeXglyph190}}


\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I guess it should be `\newfontface`, unless Wingdings has alternate shapes. One can also say `\newfontface{\myfont}{Wingdings}[Scale=2]` if the glyphs are to be magnified at every point of usage.